# VBScript to export all members of multiple Active Directory groups?

Tags: vbscript, active-directory, ldap

Is there a way of exporting *all* the members of multiple Active Directory groups at once using a VBScript?  Preferably the output would be the usernames listed under the group they are a member of.

I have the following which allows me to export the members of 1 AD Group at a time, but I am at a loss as to how to modify it to look at multiple groups.

```
On Error Resume Next
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set outfile = fso.CreateTextFile("Members.csv")
Set objGroup = GetObject("LDAP://cn=*GROUPNAME*,OU=Groups,DC=domain,DC=local")
objGroup.GetInfo

arrMembersOf = objGroup.GetEx("member")

For Each GetObject in ObjGroup
    outfile.WriteLine objGroup.Name
Next

For Each strMember in arrMembersOf
    outfile.WriteLine strMember
Next
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, this is possible, but I think you might need to change your approach slightly. You need to write an LDAP query to query two groups at once, rather than just setting your scope to a particular group.

So, try reworking your script like this:

```
  Set objRootDSE = GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE")
    strDNSDomain = objRootDSE.Get("defaultNamingContext")
  Set objRootDSE = Nothing
  Set ad = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
  Set adoConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    adoConnection.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
    adoConnection.Open "Active Directory Provider"
    ad.ActiveConnection = adoConnection

'Put the distinguishedname of your two groups here:
strFilter = "(|(memberof=CN=Group Name,OU=....)(memberof=CN=Group Name 2,OU=....))"

'Chose what you want to return here:
strAttributes = "samaccountname,cn"

strQuery = "<LDAP://" & strDNSDomain & ">" & ";" & strFilter & ";" & strAttributes & ";subtree"

  ad.CommandText = strQuery
  ad.Properties("SearchScope") = 2 
  ad.Properties("Page Size") = 1000
  ad.Properties("Cache Results") = False
Set objRS = ad.Execute
```

Now you've got all the results in a recordset, you can work your way through them writing each one to a file or whatever you want to do. So something like:

```
Do Until objRS.EOF


   'Do something with each value
   objRS.Fields("samaccountname")

objRS.MoveNext
Loop
```

Any use? I'm assuming here you know a little bit about writing LDAP queries

Answer (score 0):

The best place to find scripts for Active Directory is Microsoft's Script Center [Repository](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/).

You can find a script listing all groups and all group members [here](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/a2d6475e-50e6-4367-9aa4-c19a60674157) ("List all groups in the domain and all members of the groups").